# What are the pros and cons of supervised, semi-supervised and unsupervised relation extraction in NLP?

Tags: natural-language-processing, comparison, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

I am following the NLP course taught by Dan Jurafsky. In the video lectures [Supervised Relation Extraction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48vIACEC_w&list=PLQiyVNMpDLKnZYBTUOlSI9mi9wAErFtFm&index=50) and [Semi Supervised and Unsupervised Relation Extraction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jxqx70iX9kc&list=PLQiyVNMpDLKnZYBTUOlSI9mi9wAErFtFm&index=51) Jurafsky explains supervised, semi-supervised and unsupervised relation extraction.

But what are the pros and cons of every relation extraction method compared with the other two relation extraction methods?

Answer (score 1):

### Supervised

Pros:

- highest accuracy

Cons:

- need a large human-labeled training set
- brittle (doesn't work well with examples that are in a different genre from the training set)

### Semi-supervised

#### Relation bootstrapping

Pros:

- only requires a small set of labeled data (seed relations)

Cons:

- complex iterative process

#### Distant supervision

Pros:

- training happens in one go (no iterative process)

Cons:

- requires a big database of relations

### Unsupervised

Pros:

- don't need any labeled data

Cons:

- need to process a huge quantity of unlabeled data (usually web crawling)